# php bin/console make:entity me da error

Tags: php, symfony

Estoy utilizando Symfony y mySQL.
En la terminal, tras ejecutar `php bin/console php bin/console make:entity Software` para crear una Entity, la empieza creando pero acaba abortando y me la crea a medias.

```
 created: src/Entity/Software.php
 created: src/Repository/SoftwareRepository.php

 Entity generated! Now let's add some fields!
 You can always add more fields later manually or by re-running this command.

 New property name (press <return> to stop adding fields):
 > 

  Aborted.
```

Si ejecutp `php bin/console php bin/console make:entity` para crear una Entity desde la consola, me pregunta el nombre de la entidad pero me aborta directamente.

```
 created: src/Entity/Software.php
 created: src/Repository/SoftwareRepository.php

 Entity generated! Now let's add some fields!
 You can always add more fields later manually or by re-running this command.

 New property name (press <return> to stop adding fields):
 > 

  Aborted
```

Hasta aquí, me crea la Entity pero a la hora de hacer la migración me da este resultado:
`php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff`

```
Generated new migration class to "C:\Users\..\app_advsoftware/src/Migrations/Version20200317113545.php"

To run just this migration for testing purposes, you can use migrations:execute --up 20200317113545

To revert the migration you can use migrations:execute --down 20200317113545
```

He buscado en internet y estas dos ultimas lineas no suelen salir. Despues ejecuto: `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` y me da lo siguiente:

```
                    Application Migrations


WARNING! You are about to execute a database migration that could result in schema changes and data loss. Are you sure you wish to continue? (y/n)

  Aborted.
```

En el momento en el que tengo que poner (y/n), lo aborta directamente y en la base de datos no añade nada.

Gracias

Comment: Has llegado a escribir algo cuando te pide el property name? O directamente sale todo el texto y se acaba la ejecución del comando?

Comment: Directamente me aborta en todos los casos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo he solucionado creando todo en phpMyAdmin directamente

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/201957)

Comment: He encontrado yo mismo la solución ;)